# change default python version with virtualenvwrapper (& virtualenv)

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've recently changed my python setup so that's it's now installed with brew.  Previously when using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper it would default to setting up a new virtualenv using python3 (used for most of my projects).  Now unfortunately the default is python2.  I can install python3 using:

```
mkproject -p python3 projectname
```

however how can i make python3 the default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> To automatically use a custom Python binary instead of the one
>   virtualenv is run with you can also set an environment variable:
>
> ```
> $ export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/opt/python-3.3/bin/python
> $ virtualenv ENV
> ```
>
> It’s the same as passing the option to virtualenv directly:
>
> ```
> $ virtualenv --python=/opt/python-3.3/bin/python ENV
> ```

Source: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference.html#configuration